# VS Code auto-completion with std and other libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code, I have installed C/C++ extension of Microsoft for auto completion. It works for everything in my own project, but my real interest is having auto-completion for things that are not in my project, for example the `std` lib.
If I declare, for example

`std::fstream mystream;`

I would like to then see the functions of the `fstream` when I put my dot next to mystream.

I found out a bit on how to do that, maybe it would be by going into the `c_cpp_propertiese.json` file but from there, I do not know what to do because I do not know where the `std` is located or how I would need to write what is necessary.

So the real question is, how do I add inside the configuration files of the extension C/C++ some includes in order for my VS Code to autocomplete any external libraries?

Thank you, may this help for other people trying to use VS Code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't something you're going to fix yourself.

The problem that you're facing is that you need compiler assistance. In the "real" Visual Studio, that's provided by Intellisense. This includes a C++ compiler (surprisingly enough, not Microsoft's own but EDG's). Since it's a compiler, it's smart enough to figure out what `std::fstream` really is: `std::basic_fstream<char>`, a template. Instantiating that gives Intellisense a list of members.

But without the Intellisense compiler, VS Code cannot figure out the members of that template.

Answer (score -3):

It works in my VS2008, while you must include the corresponding header file firstly.

Comment: I did include the header, it is visual studio code, its not like the other versions of visual studio, its also available on linux.